# Compare and highlight difference in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 2 excel workbook. The first workbook have only 1 sheet while the other workbook contains a few sheets. Instead of having to manually search the value in the second worksheet base on the first, is there a way to compare and highlight differences?

Have tried Conditional Formatting with `=A1<>Sheet2!A1` but it highlighted the whole column even though there should be matching values probably due to different arrangement of values.

Please refer to simplified example below. I need to highlight the values in Workbook B that could not be found in Workbook A

-Update-

**Example**

> Excel workbook A:

Sheet 1

1. B27
2. 124
3. A25
4. 126
5. 127
6. A23
7. B24
8. 125
9. A26
10. 123
11. B23
12. A24
13. B25
14. B26
15. A27
16. C123
17. D789
18. AAZX
19. ABCD

> Excel workbook B:

Sheet 1

1. 123
2. 124
3. 125
4. 126
5. 127
6. N123

Sheet 2

1. A23
2. A24
3. A25
4. A26
5. A27
6. N456

Sheet 3

1. B23
2. B24
3. B25
4. B26
5. B27
6. N789

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, provide some examples.

Comment: You can try using [brettdj's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641067/brettdj) addin's.

Comment: I've added an example, hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of Office, press the windows key and search for "spreadsheet compare". It enables you to compare two versions of a workbook.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that however the list contains hundreds of columns and I am looking for an alternative instead of manually comparing the 2 excel workbooks.